# how to change four hexadecimal number to float in js?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Like this :

I hava a float number `25.56`,I could translate it to the four hexadecimal number `E1 7A CC 41` in js.And the translate way is called as union in C.

But I don't know how to change the `E1 7A CC 41` to the float in js

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far??

Comment: I think the OP meant something like `new Uint8ClampedArray(new Float32Array([25.56]).buffer)`. The expected result (`E1 7A CC 41`) can be seen like this: `Array.from(new Uint8ClampedArray(new Float32Array([25.56]).buffer)).map(function(a){return a.toString(16)})`. The other way around is also possible in JavaScript, but the duplicate target suggested by adeneo is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll have to work with [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) and [array buffers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer):

```
Array.from(
  new Uint8ClampedArray(       // Represents the four bytes…
    new Float32Array([25.56])  // …of this number
      .buffer
  )
).map(function(a){
  return a.toString(16);
});
```

This returns the array `[ "e1", "7a", "cc", "41" ]`.

The other way around works as well:

```
new Float32Array(
  new Uint8ClampedArray(
    ["e1", "7a", "cc", "41"].map(function(a){
      return parseInt(a, 16);
    })
  ).buffer
);
```

**Note:** This doesn’t quite return a `Float32Aray` with `25.56`, but `25.559999465942383`, because that’s all the precision you get with a 32 bit float number. With a `Float64Array`, you’d get the hex array `["8f", "c2", "f5", "28", "5c", "8f", "39", "40"]` and then you’d get the number `25.56` back, precisely.

These APIs are only supported since Firefox 4, Chrome 7 and Internet Explorer 10.

---

The constructors `Uint8ClampedArray` and `Float32Array` can get a length as their argument, an array or an `ArrayBuffer`.

When they get an array, a new typed array is created from that array.

When they get an `ArrayBuffer`, a new typed array is created based on the contents of the buffer.